# How to get title of web page with libcurl

Tags: c, http, libcurl

How can I get the title of web page with curl? I wish to pass http or https url and get title of that page. I figured out that `curl_easy_perform(curl)` prints the html to terminal but I can't figure out how I can parse the html.

Comment: You need to set a callback that stores the received page in memory, then parse the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libcurl is not a HTML parsing library, it's focus is on the transport, i.e. getting you the bits. You need to either interpret them yourself, or turn to other libraries.

In your case you need to look for the `<title>` element and extract that element's text.

It's a bit too large to paste here, but [this example from libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html) shows how to save content in memory in C. It uses the  `curl_easy_setopt()` function to register a `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` callback which receives all the data.

Note that the libcurl example uses an "exact-fitting" dynamic string, i.e. it calls `realloc()` every time it gets more data. This is generally not the best approach but it's of course simple to implement and understand and might make sense in an example.

Comment: Ok but how can i have libcurl to fetch html to variable or structure so i can search for <title>?

Comment: Another example from the web site that even extracts the <title> tag is: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/htmltitle.html

Answer (score 0):

libcurl doesn't parse html for you. You need to use other libraries for that or write your own parser.

Have a look at HTML tidy. The Lib curl page has an [example](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/htmltidy.html).

If you want just a title you may try a simple solution using std::string search or regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <regex>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

//Convert curl out to string
size_t curl_to_string(char* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* data)
{
    std::string* str = (std::string*)data;
    int x;

    for (x = 0; x < size * nmemb; ++x)
    {
        (*str) += ptr[x];
    }

    return size * nmemb;
}

std::string curlGetHtmlSource(std::string& link)
{
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string html_txt;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, &link[0]);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curl_to_string);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &html_txt);

        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* Check for errors */
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
                curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
                throw std::runtime_error("Can't get html source");
        }

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    
    return html_txt;
}

//Pars regex from text
std::string stringRegex(const std::string& in_string , const std::string& regx)
{
    const std::regex pattern{ regx };

    for (
        std::sregex_iterator it(in_string.begin(), in_string.end(), pattern);
        it != std::sregex_iterator{};
        ++it
        )                                                               
    {
        return (*it)[1];
    }
    return {};
}

//Replace html entities
std::string entityParser(std::string text) {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> convert({
        {"&quot;", "\""},
        {"&apos;", "'"},
        {"&amp;", "&"},
        {"&gt;", ">"},
        {"&lt;", "<"},
        {"&frasl;", "/"}
        });
    std::string res = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); ++i) 
    {
        bool flag = false;
        for (auto it = begin(convert); it != end(convert); ++it) 
        {
            std::string key = it->first;
            std::string value = it->second;
            if (i + key.size() - 1 < text.size()) 
            {
                if (text.substr(i, key.size()) == key) 
                {
                    res += value;
                    i += static_cast<int>(key.size() - 1);
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!flag) {
            res += text[i];
        }
    }
    return res;
}

std::string getTitle(std::string& link)
{
    std::string title = curlGetHtmlSource(link);
    title = stringRegex(title, R"(<title>([^<]*)<)");
    title = entityParser(title);
    return title ;
}

int main()
{
    std::string link = "https://example.com";
    getTitle(link);
}
```

Sources:

curl_to_string - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525631/17061201

curlGetHtmlSource- https://curl.se/libcurl/c/simple.html

entityParser- https://helloacm.com/a-simple-html-entity-parser-in-c/